# How to reference an object instance in callable decorator object with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, scoping

### Context:

I'd like to be able to decorate functions so that I can track their stats.  Using [this](http://www.lorieau.com/methods-and-reference/research-and-computer-methods/42-mods-method-object-decorators.html) post as a reference I went about trying to make my own callable decorator objects.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
def Stats(fn):
    Class StatsObject(object):
        def __init__(self, fn):
            self.fn = fn
            self.stats = {}

        def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
            self.stats['times_called'] = self.stats.get('times_called', 0) + 1
            return self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)

    function = StatsObject(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args **kwargs):
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

Class MockClass(object):
    @Stats
    def mock_fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do things
```

### Problem:

This actually calls the mock_fn function correctly but I don't have a reference to the stats object outside the wrapper function. i.e. I can't do:

```
mc = MockClass()
mc.mock_fn()
mc.mock_fn.stats
# HasNoAttribute Exception
```

Then I tried changing the following code recognizing that it was a scoping issue:

From:

```
    function = StatsObject(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args **kwargs):
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

To:

```
    function = StatsObject(fn)
    return function
```

But of course I lost the self reference (self becomes the StatsObject instance, obj becomes the first arg, and the MockClass object self reference gets lost).

So I understand why the first issue is happening, but not the second.  Is there any way that I can pass the self reference of MockClass to the StatsObject `__call__` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions can actually themselves have attributes in Python.

```
def Stats(fn):
    class StatsObject(object):
        def __init__(self, fn):
            self.fn = fn
            self.stats = {}

        def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
            self.stats['times_called'] = self.stats.get('times_called', 0) + 1
            return self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)

    function = StatsObject(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args **kwargs):
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # KEY LINE BELOW: make the StatsObject available outside as "stats_fn"
    wrapper.stats_fn = function

    return wrapper

class MockClass(object):
    @Stats
    def mock_fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do things
```

The key line is assigning the `StatsObject` instance (which you've, perhaps misleadingly, locally named `function`) as an attribute of the function *which you return from the decorator*.

Once you do this, `self.mock_fn.stats_fn.stats` (not `self.mock_fn()`! The attribute is on the function, not its return value) will work within an instance of `MockClass`, and `MockClass.mock_fn.stats_fn.stats` will be available outside. The statistics will be global across all instances of `MockClass` (since the decorator is called once, not once per instance), which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This is a great response!  I'm aware that functions are objects, but I completely forgot about it while writing this up.  I'm curious though, what happens to `self` when it's passed into the second example.

When I loaded up pdb, I noticed that in the second example (where I just returned the callable object back from the decorator) that self becomes the StatsObject reference, and the obj argument becomes the first argument of mock_fn.  The self reference in the scope of the MockClass disappears.

Comment: @Caustic it doesn't change value! *Inside* of `wrapper`, `self` is an instance of `MockClass`. So if you want per-instance statistics, you can keep a nested dict `stats[mockclass_instance]['times_called']`. You're passing that instance as the `obj` argument to `StatsObject.__call__`.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my response; but what you said made it click for me.  Thanks!